# Как правильно организовать авторизацию в Angular приложении?

Tags: авторизация, angularjs, auth

При открытии приложения сначала открывается главная страница, после загрузки всего приложения срабатывает location.href('/login');

Как организовать авторизацию в приложении, так, что бы посторонним не было доступно ничего кроме формы логина и пароля?

И как закрыть файлы приложения, например:
в каталоге приложения есть каталог с экранными формами и прочими компонентами приложения ( pages/abonents.html ). Если в адресной строке указать прямой путь к файлу, то он доступен всем. Как сделать его доступным только после авторизации?

Answer (score 2):

Без серверного кода никак. На серверной стороне необходимо разрешить только авторизованный доступ к /pages/*, файлам скриптов angular-приложения и другим ресурсам, которые должен видеть пользователь только после авторизации.

Логин-страница, по-хорошему, тоже должна генерироваться и проверяться сервером. Даже если и будут какие-то проверки на стороне клиента, сервер должен перепроверить передаваемые данные перед тем, как авторизовать пользователя. Будет хорошо, если сервер ещё проверит csrf token.